# Quickest way to add all the fields to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to copy all the fields from the `temp_sales` table to `sales` table (after specific field). I want to do it quickest way as possible.. How to do this in SQL?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_sales` (
  `field1` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `field3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `field4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `field5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `field6` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `field7` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `field8` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `field9` tinyint(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13692 ;
```

In other word: There are some fields in the sales table. I want to add more new **fields** in the `sales` table from `temp_sales` (without data).

Comment: If you explain what you need this for, maybe we can offer alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 3-Step process:

.1. You need some unique or primary key field in `temp_sales`, that links a row in `temp_sales` to the corresponding row in `sales` (again via a unique/primary key)

.2. You need a DDL statement such as

```
ALTER TABLE `sales` 
  ADD COLUMN `field1`VARCHAR(10) AFTER `whatever`,
  ADD COLUMN `field2`VARCHAR(10) AFTER `fields2`,
...
```

.3. You need a DML statement such as

```
UPDATE `sales` 
INNER JOIN `temp_sales` ON `sales`.`keyfield`=`temp_sales`.`keyfield`
SET `sales`.`field1`=`tempsales`.`field1`,
  `sales`.`field2`=`tempsales`.`field2`,
  ...
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE `sales` ADD COLUMN` still take times write it up. I got like 30 fields to add :(

Comment: There is no way around that. Copy-Paste is what you need. Just to make that clear: There is no way in MySQL to reference field names as data - DDL and DML can not be intermixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
  mysql> create table new_table_name as(select * from existing_table_name);

//It will also populate existing table data to new table if present
//If old table is empty then it will create same copy of that table

In your case:
 mysql> create table sales as(select * from temp_sales);
```